# Laravel(how to bring two columns from two separate tables in one .blade file) without touching the DB?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the most effective way for returning data from two tables in on view?

Like an employee check the vehicle for each order.

```
Route::get('orderVehicle',"adminController@orderVehicle");


public function orderVehicle(Request $reques){
    $orders = new Order;
    $vehicles = new Vehicle;   $orders->id;   $vehicles->id; return view('adminVeiw.orderVehicle',compact('orders','vehicles')); }


@foreach($orders as $or)   {{ $or->id }} @endforeach   {{ $vehicles->id }}
```

And the error is

> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/full-Restaurant-App-Using-Laravel/resources/views/adminVeiw/orderVehicle.blade.php)"

So any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want but, `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` means you're trying to access a property that does not exists, probably this error is because `{{ $vehicles->id }}`, when you do `new Vehicle` it create a new collection of that model, but not fetch the rows of your DB, if you want to fetch data you must do `YourModel::get()` if you could describe your question better, we could give you a better answer

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense: You're creating a new instance of your models and passing that into the view. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i mean how to bring  two columns from two separate  tables in one  .blade file     that a user can see them

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are saying but you can use [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) in Laravel models so you can access multiple tables' columns in your view like `$post->user['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

do this if you don't wanna change your code in controller

```
@foreach($orders as $or)
     @if(!empty($or->id))
        {{ $or->id }}
     @endif
@endforeach


@if(!empty($vahicles->id))
     {{ $vehicles->id }}
@endif
```

in this case you won't get error but i don't know how you wanna this works for you,
i hope it helps

Comment: now am getting  a white screen(every thing was declared  as empty ) .

Comment: so you find what is your problem, `$vahicles` and `$or` have no `id` fields, check it in your controller befor it take back to your view

Comment: $orders->id;
$vehicles->id;                                                                                                                          are already their but i don't know why  this vars can't call id  from DB

Answer (score -1):

```
public function orderVehicle() 
{      
    $orders = Order::create();
    $vehicles = Vehicle::create();   

    return view('adminVeiw.orderVehicle', compact('orders', 'vehicles')); 
}
```

Comment: it returns  1  1     on the screen  but when  {{$orders->id}} {{$orders->quantity}}       i got                                                                                                                               "Call to undefined method App\Order::render() (View: /var/www/html/full-Restaurant-App-Using-Laravel/resources/views/adminVeiw/orderVehicle.blade.php)"

Comment: or         @foreach($orders as $orders)
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{$orders->id}}</th>

Comment: returns                                                                                                                    "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/full-Restaurant-App-Using-Laravel/resources/views/adminVeiw/orderVehicle.blade.php)"